# Model keeps printing hollow

Tags: modeling, faces, 3d-printing

Hello!

First off, I'm a huge noob to blender, this is my first few months with a new program.

I'm having trouble printing my model. It's a fully formed mesh, completely connected. But when I go to print it, it becomes a hollow, spaghetti nightmare. Is there anything I should do to it before printing? Maybe an increased solidify modifier?

It doesn't matter if I print it bigger or smaller, there are still completely missing faces, and everywhere from the knees to the neck are totally hollow.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you link us the mesh please? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com
Also you may want to run through a checklist such as https://www.shapeways.com/tutorials/things-to-keep-in-mind If I had a guess I would say there may be some illegal geometry.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, could you add some pictures or a link to your .blend file to the question to clarify the problem?

Comment: There is a 3D Printing [addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/preferences/addons.html) included with blender that you should enable, it may help find the issue. I expect it may be the face normals, in edit mode select all and press Ctrl-N

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! Turns out I had an unnecessary inner shell that needed deleting. I fixed it by removing doubles and inner faces, as well as cleaning some illegal geometry. Thanks again!